# How to send an is-less-than symbol in JSON payload

Tags: json

I want to send a `<` symbol in JSON payload.

It always fails.  I  tried the ASCII code (%3d) but it didn't work.

I tried

```
"sign":"<"
"sign":"%3d"
```

Does anyone know how to insert this symbol?

Comment: Are you decoding URIEncoded requests on the backend? Some code would help us determine what your problem is. Please try and create a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.

Comment: Your problem seems to not be relative to JSON but url encoding. Lokk at this link http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp . %3C is probably what you need.